# Using nextPageToken in Youtube API

Tags: python, pandas

I know there is something simple that I'm not getting here, but I'm new to this, and trying to get my head around some basic principles. Tried some other iterations and seemed to be looping forever. Here's my code so far, I'm looking to use nextPageToken to create a list of data from this youtube channel. Can somebody please help me make this work?

```py
def get_videos(df): 

   
    pageToken = ""
    url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key="+API_KEY+"&channelId="+CHANNEL_ID+"&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=10000"

    response = requests.get(url).json()
    time.sleep(1)
    

   
    for video in response['items']:
        if video['id']['kind'] == "youtube#video":
        
                video_id = video['id']['videoId']
                video_title = video['snippet']['title']
                video_title = str(video_title).replace("&amp;","")
                upload_date= video['snippet']['publishedAt']
                upload_date = str(upload_date).split("T")[0]
                
                view_count, like_count, comment_count = get_video_details(video_id)   
                
    next_page_token = response.get('nextPageToken') 
    while next_page_token is not None:
            response = requests.get(url).json()
            for video in response['items']:
                if video['id']['kind'] == "youtube#video":

                    video_id = video['id']['videoId']
                    video_title = video['snippet']['title']
                    video_title = str(video_title).replace("&amp;","")
                    upload_date= video['snippet']['publishedAt']
                    upload_date = str(upload_date).split("T")[0]

                    view_count, like_count, comment_count = get_video_details(video_id)   
                next_page_token = response.get('nextPageToken') 
            
                
            return df
                #save the data in pandas df

            df = df.append({'video_id' :video_id, 'video_title':video_title,
                                'upload_date':upload_date, 'view_count':view_count,
                               'like_count':like_count, 'comment_count':comment_count}, ignore_index=True)
```